# unsigned char inbuf[1024000] throw an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, exc-bad-access

I'm developing an iOS application with latest SDK.

This app has some C++ classes.

When I call a method for that class I get an error:

This is part of the C++ class.

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
    const char* path = jFileName ;
    const char* tempPath =  jTempFileName ;

    const char* truckPath = jTruckFileName;
    const char* truckTempPath = jTruckTempFileName;
#endif

    MyFunction(path,tempPath);
```

On `MyFunction(path,tempPath);`, `path` and `tempPath` has a valid value.

But, I get the error here:

```
void MyFunction(const char* inFileName, const char* outFileName)
{
    [ ... ]
    unsigned char inbuf[1024000], outbuf[1024000];

    [ ... ]
}
```

Adding comments I have found that the error is here: `unsigned char inbuf[1024000], outbuf[1024000];` when I the function only has that line.

This error only appears on a device.

**How can I know where is the problem?**

Comment: @V-Xtreme I don't get any log. I've updated the question with more details (I have found where the error is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stack is not that large:

```
 unsigned char inbuf[1024000], outbuf[1024000];
```

use a heap allocation instead:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> inbuf(1024000, 0), outbuf(1024000, 0);
```

or divide your work up so a smaller stack buffer can be used.

---

*The compiler is not required to put your buffers on the stack, but it probably has in this case.*

Answer (score 1):

Answering for

> How can I know where is the problem?

try debugging with **exception breakpoint enabled.**

1. Go to the breakpoint navigator
2. click on the "+" sign
3. click Add exception breakpoint
4. click "Done"

Also try debugging with enabled zombie objects. For that go to **Product->Edit Scheme** and check the "**Enable zombie object**"

Comment: I've updated the question with more details (I have found where the error is).

Comment: `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` is not a language-level exception that can be caught using the breakpoint.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe doesn't EXEC_BAD_ACCESS occur when a deallocated object is referred to? (Basically bad memory management)

Comment: Right. It's a unix signal that means that the processor tried to access invalid memory. It occurs when dereferencing random values which happens frequently adter an object has been released and new stuff has been written to the same spot in memory. Yet, the signal is not catchable using language level exception handling.